# file_get_contents into a json variable- twitter module

Tags: php, javascript, json, file-upload, twitter

I am extremely new to json and have been working on this issue for about a week.

I used php to retrieve tweets from a list of accounts and stored them into a .txt file

```
$cache = dirname(__FILE__) . '/../cache/twitter-json.txt';

$data = file_get_contents('http://api.twitter.com/1/lists/statuses.json?    slug=widget&owner_screen_name=webcodepro&count=1&page=1&per_page=8&include_rts=true&include_entities=true');    

    $cachefile = fopen($cache, 'wb');
    fwrite($cachefile,utf8_encode($data));
    fclose($cachefile);

?>
```

The way the architect has the front-end page structured is that I need to store the json value (what I have in the .txt file) into a json  variable in a .js file and render it.

edit:
so it has been changed to

```
$cache =_ _DIR__.'/cached.txt'; 
$data = file_get_contents('http://api.twitter.com/1/lists/statuses.json?    slug=widget&owner_screen_name=webcodepro&count=1&page=1&per_page=8&include_rts=true&include_entities=true'); 

file_put_contents($cache, $data);
```

the file comes up empty.  do you guys know what might be the problem?

Is it possible to store the contents of a .txt file into a json variable in a .js file?

Comment: Why do you `utf8_encode` the data? I'll bet my first-born that you are only creating problems doing that.

Comment: @deceze Noticed that as well but it's perfectly safe as JSON doesn't use non-ASCII characters in any way.

Comment: @Tom That's not guaranteed, JSON-the-data-format can contain UTF-8 characters. JSON-as-output-by-PHP doesn't.

Comment: @deceze Twitter guarantees ASCII-only JSON. But you're right - JSON can have UTF-8 characters. Still no need to `utf8_encode`, of course, as JSON is already UTF-8.

Comment: utf8_encode($data) ?????????????????

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. No need to `utf8_encode` things as JSON is already UTF-8
2. You can simply use `file_put_contents`
3. `file_put_contents($cache, 'var myvar = '.$data.';');`

-edit-
Code to clarify my solution:

```
$cache = __DIR__.'/cached.txt';
$data = file_get_contents('http://api.twitter.com/1/lists/statuses.json?slug=widget&owner_screen_name=webcodepro&count=1&page=1&per_page=8&include_rts=true&include_entities=true');
file_put_contents($cache, 'var mydata = '.$data.';');
```

Comment: You may need to add `myvar` to global space.

Comment: @Florent When you add this as a `<script src="cached.js">`, you can simply access it as `myvar` from other scripts.

Comment: oh awesome thanks guys.  forgive me for I am very new to this.  so can i do $cache=cached.js ?

Comment: Yes Christina, $cache is simply the location of the file that you are writing to. As a note if $cache = 'cached.js', cached.js must be in the same directory as the root PHP script that is running.

Comment: I'd suggest you don't attempt to do that. You can however decode JSON into an array `json_decode($data,true)` the `true` bit makes sure it's an array. And then merge two arrays with `array_merge()` or a custom function and finally `json_encode($merged_arrays)` to create your new JSON object. Now just write that to the file.

Comment: oh awesome.  Thank you so much so now after the $data assignment it looks like this json_deode($data, true); 
$merged_arrays = array_merge($data); 
$obj=json_encode($merged_arrays); 

 $cachefile = fopen($cache, 'wb');
    file_put_contents($cache, 'var myvar= '.$obj';');
    fclose($cachefile);

Comment: the .js file is empty now though.  Do you know why that might be?

Comment: @Christina Don't do the fopen/fclose things, they're not needed. Also don't listen to @DavidBarker. All you need after doing `$data = file_get_contents(...)` is the line I wrote at #3

Comment: oh awesome thank you so much.   when i put the url onto my browser it outputs the json value but when I try to output it onto the javascript file it is still empty.  I tried having the js file initially empty then having the js file initially having var myvar={}  do you know why this emptiness might be?

Comment: haha actually Tom, I have found that technique quite useful at times especially when I have multiple JSON objects i want to mess around with. Saying don't listen to someone because hey offer a slightly off the wall solution is a little rude. Thank you for your time

Comment: @DavidBarker Apologies if I sounded rude. In this case that's not relevant though and as you can see it only confused Christina.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to store the contents of a .txt file into a json variable in a .js file?

Yes, it is possible:

```
$txtFile  = '/path/to/txt-file.txt';
$jsFile   = '/path/to/js-file.js';
$jsPlate  = "var jsVariable = %s;\n";

$string   = file_get_contents($txtFile);
if (FALSE === $string) {
    throw new RuntimeException('Failed to load text-file.');
}

$json     = json_encode($string);
if (FALSE === $json) {
    throw new RuntimeException('Failed to json encode string.');
}

$jsString = sprintf($jsPlate, $json);
$result   = file_put_contents($jsFile, $jsString);
if (!$result) {
    throw new RuntimeException('Failed to save javascript-file.');
}
```

Encoding Checklist:

- The text-file is UTF-8 encoded.

Comment: thank you @hakre but strangely my .js file is still empty :-(  It is saved within the same directory so it is written as $jsFile="/cached.js"  Do you know what the cause of that might be?  Am I writing the path incorrectly?

Comment: `/cached.js` is not within the same directory. try this instead: `$jsFile = dirname(__FILE__) . '/cached.js';`. That is inside the same directory as your `script.php` where the php code is in.